# Can't set a vector of 4 floatx32 with ARM NEON intrinsics

Tags: c, arm, simd, neon

I want to load some values from a table and set them into a vector:
**in the first case set the four values of the vector to a:**

```
float32x4_t dest = vdupq_n_f32(a);
```

this was so obvious when I read the intrinsics manual.

**in the second case set the four values of the vector to different values from a table. This was a little bit tricky because there is no instruction for that, so I did the following:**

```
float32x4_t dest = {a3,a2,a1,a0};
```

it's not an intrinsic but, basing on other publications and forums on the Net it was the only solution for me. Sadly, I'm getting this error:

```
error: expected expression before ‘{’ token
```

Anyone could help or have an alternative for this?

Comment: What compiler are you using ? This should work with gcc, clang, et al.

Comment: ARM-gnueabi-gcc  with eclipse Mars

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your compiler does not support direct initialisation like this (i.e. you're using something other than gcc or clang), then you'll need to load the values explicitly, e.g.

```
const float init[4] = {a3,a2,a1,a0};
float32x4_t dest = vld1q_f32(init);
```

Note that your first example appears to be wrong - if you're trying to set all 4 vector elements to the same value (like SSE's `_mm_set1_ps`) then you'll want to use something like `vdupq_n_f32`.

Comment: Ahh I'm seeking performance .... like this all other instructions will wait until the init array is filled then loaded into dest

Comment: Normally this kind of vector initialisation is done only once, e.g. at the start of a function, before any performance-critical loops, so a few cycles here or there should make no difference to performance. If you look at the code generated for e.g. `_mm_set_ps` you will see that it too typically results in a number of instructions (don't be fooled into thinking that all intrinsics map to a single instruction).

Comment: you are 100% right but the problem that the setting thing is called many times in a loop ... in the X86 version the timing is great but in the ARM version is not as expected ... For ARM the serial version is so much faster then the SIMD version and this what confused me.

Comment: OK - you might need to take a more holistic approach to your SSE->Neon porting then - just doing a 1:1 translation might not be the best approach. There may be better Neon-specific instructions that you can exploit to achieve your performance goals in a slightly different way. Good luck!

Comment: @A.nechi Ultimately, regardless of how you choose to express it in C, given fixed-width 32-bit instruction encodings you're never going to get 128 bits of arbitrary data into a register without several instructions and/or memory accesses. If `a0`, `a1`, etc. represent things which are arbitrarily scattered around and can't be made contiguous without a temporary copy, then consider explicitly building up the vector by loading them each directly with `vld1q_lane_f32()`.

Comment: You might want to take a look at [DirectXMath](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXMath) for some side-by-side SSE vs. ARM-NEON implementations of various functions. For "vector constants" the library uses the type ``XMVECTORF32`` and generally declares them ``static const``. That means they are loaded from the read-only data segment, but it's one of the faster ways to load an arbitrary vector in SSE or in ARM-NEON. If you are setting a single value to all channels, then ``vdupq_n_f32`` is a good choice (alas SSE doesn't have anything better than the compound ``_mm_set_ps1``).

Comment: Note:[AVX](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2012/09/11/directxmath-avx/) does have ``_mm_broadcast_ss`` which is equivalent to ARM-NEON ``vld1q_dup_f32`` which at least eliminates the shuffles that are added by the ``_mm_load_ps1`` and ``_mm_set_ps1`` compound intrinics.